# How to create table from a select query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, create-table

I've got "table1" with "id" and line geometry column ("geom_line"). I want to create "table2" whereas it's filled by select all lines which is within a polygon. I wrote following code. May anybody correct, please?

```
SELECT id, ST_Intersection(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((443425 4427680, 441353 4427680, 441368 4426075, 443762 4426149, 443425 4427680))', 32650)
, geom_line)
    FROM trajectory where geom_line IS NOT null
```

INTO table2
FROM mydatabase

Answer (score 3):

Creating a table based on a select is done using `create table ... as select ...` in standard SQL - and Postgres supports this as well:

```
create table table2
as
SELECT id, ST_Intersection(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((443425 4427680, 441353 4427680, 441368 4426075, 443762 4426149, 443425 4427680))', 32650)    , geom_line)
FROM trajectory 
where geom_line IS NOT null
```

More details as usual in the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtableas.html

Answer (score 0):

Following is also one of the option for your requirement(Supports in MS-SQL)

```
SELECT ColumnName1,ColumnName1 INTO TableTest FROM Your_Table
```

Comment: PostgreSQL supports this syntax, but it's non-standard and deprecated. `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ...` should be preferred.